# How to add a Button to my EmptyView?

Tags: java, android

Hi I'm trying to insert a `Button` into an`EmptyView`. The only thing I can seem to get to work is the `EmptyText` where a text value is displayed when the list is empty. This code works for just displaying a `textview`. How can I successfully add a button to the view?

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ListFragment;
import android.text.format.DateFormat;
import android.view.ActionMode;
import android.view.ContextMenu;
import android.view.ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AbsListView.MultiChoiceModeListener;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.robertrichardson.crimeproofassistant.R.string;

public class crimeListFragment extends ListFragment {

    private ArrayList<crime> mcrime;
    private boolean mSubtitleVisible;
    public static final String TAG = "crimeListFragment";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        getActivity().setTitle(R.string.app_name);
        mcrime = crimeLab.get(getActivity()).getcrime();
        crimeAdapter adapter = new crimeAdapter(mcrime);
        setListAdapter(adapter);
        setRetainInstance(true);
        mSubtitleVisible = false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view,  savedInstanceState);

        setEmptyText(getResources().getString(string.new_crime_attack_empty_desc));

        registerForContextMenu(getListView());
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
}


    @TargetApi(11)
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          View v = super.onCreateView(inflater,  parent,  savedInstanceState);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
            if (mSubtitleVisible) {
                getActivity().getActionBar().setSubtitle(R.string.subtitle);
            }
        }

        ListView listView = (ListView)v.findViewById(android.R.id.list);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
            // Use floating point context menus on Froyer and Gingerbread
            registerForContextMenu(listView);
        } else {
            // Use contextual action bar on Honeycomb and higher
            listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL);
            listView.setMultiChoiceModeListener(new MultiChoiceModeListener()  {

            // ActionMode.Callback methods
            public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
                MenuInflater inflater = mode.getMenuInflater();
                inflater.inflate(R.menu.crime_list_item_context, menu);
                return true;
            }

            public void onItemCheckedStateChanged(ActionMode mode, int position,
                    long id, boolean checked) {
            // required but not used in this implementation
             }

            public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
                switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.menu_item_delete_crime:
                    crimeAdapter adapter = (crimeAdapter)getListAdapter();
                    crimeLab crimeLab = crimeLab.get(getActivity());
                    for (int i = adapter.getCount() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                        if (getListView().isItemChecked(i)) {
                            crimeLab.deletecrime(adapter.getItem(i));
                        }
                    }
                    mode.finish();
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    return true;
                default:
                    return false;
                }

            }

            public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
                return false;
            // Required, but not used in this implementation
            }

            public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {

            }
        }); 
    }
        return v;
    }

    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        crime c = ((crimeAdapter)getListAdapter()).getItem(position);
        // Start crime Activity
        Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), crimePagerActivity.class);
        i.putExtra(crimeFragment.EXTRA_crime_ID, c.getId());
        startActivity(i);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        ((crimeAdapter)getListAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.fragment_crime_list, menu);
        MenuItem showSubtitle = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_item_show_subtitle);
        if (mSubtitleVisible && showSubtitle != null) {
            showSubtitle.setTitle(R.string.hide_subtitle);
        }
     }

    @TargetApi(11)
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.menu_item_new_crime:
            crime crime = new crime();
            crimeLab.get(getActivity()).addcrime(crime);
            Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), crimePagerActivity.class);
            i.putExtra(crimeFragment.EXTRA_crime_ID,  crime.getId());
            startActivityForResult(i,0);
            return true;
        case R.id.menu_item_show_subtitle:
            if (getActivity().getActionBar().getSubtitle() != null) {
                getActivity().getActionBar().setSubtitle(R.string.subtitle);
                mSubtitleVisible = true;
                item.setTitle(R.string.hide_subtitle);
            } else {
                getActivity().getActionBar().setSubtitle(null);
                mSubtitleVisible = false;
                item.setTitle(R.string.show_subtitle);
            }
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
     }

    @Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu,View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
        getActivity().getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.crime_list_item_context, menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo)item.getMenuInfo();
        int position = info.position;
        crimeAdapter adapter = (crimeAdapter)getListAdapter();
        crime crime = adapter.getItem(position);

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
           case R.id.menu_item_delete_crime:
               crimeLab.get(getActivity()).deletecrime(crime);
               adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
               return true;
        }
        return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
    }

    private class crimeAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<crime> {
        public crimeAdapter(ArrayList<crime> crime) {
            super(getActivity(), 0, crime);
        }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        // If we weren't given a view, inflate one
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = getActivity().getLayoutInflater()
                    .inflate(R.layout.list_item_crime, null);
        }  

        // Enter the view of this crime Attack
        crime c = getItem(position);

        TextView titleTextView =
                (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.crime_list_item_titleTextView);
        titleTextView.setText(c.getTitle());
        TextView dateTextView =
                (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.crime_list_item_dateTextView);
        dateTextView.setText(DateFormat.format("EEEE, MMM dd, yyyy  hh : mm a", c.getDate()).toString());

        CheckBox resolvedCheckBox =
                (CheckBox)convertView.findViewById(R.id.crime_list_item_resolvedCheckBox);
        resolvedCheckBox.setChecked(c.isResolved());

        return convertView;
    }
}

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        ((crimeAdapter)getListAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
 }    


Here's my XML:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:background="#f2f3f4"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  >
 <ListView
  android:id="@android:id/list"
  android:background="#f2f3f4"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  >
 </ListView>
 <linearLayout
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent" 
  android:background="#f2f3f4"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  >
 <TextView
  android:id="@android:id/empty"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:paddingLeft="4dp"
  android:paddingRight="4dp"
  android:text="@string/new__empty_desc" 
  />
 <Button
  android:id="@+id/addButton"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:paddingLeft="4dp"
  android:paddingRight="4dp"
  android:text="@string/new_attack_empty" 
  />
 </linearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: There is too much code, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 1):

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private CustomBaseAdapter customBaseAdapter;
    private ListView lv;
    private Button btn;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        FrameLayout fl = new FrameLayout(this);
        btn = new Button(this);
        btn.setText("Hit me");

        lv = new ListView(this);

        customBaseAdapter = new CustomBaseAdapter(this);
        lv.setAdapter(customBaseAdapter);

        fl.addView(lv);
        fl.addView(btn);
        setContentView(fl);

        handleVisbility();
    }

    public void handleVisbility() {
        if (customBaseAdapter.getCount() == 0) {
            lv.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            btn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            lv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            btn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }

    public class CustomBaseAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        private Context context;
        View superView;

        public CustomBaseAdapter(Context context) {
            this.context = context;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 1;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int arg0) {
            return new Object();
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int arg0) {
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int arg0, View arg1, ViewGroup arg2) {

            FrameLayout fl = new FrameLayout(context);

            Button btn = new Button(context);
            btn.setText("Hello, im a Button");

            btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Yay hit me again", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });

            fl.addView(btn);

            return fl;
        }

    }

}
```

Ok, this is kinda what you want to do here. It shows a ListView, if there is an Item in the List, and will show the Button if the List is Empty. Only thing you have to do, is to call handleVisbility() everytime you make a change to the ListViews content. Especially after you add something to the List.

Comment: What I'm trying to do is add a Button to an EmptyView and implement it with the EmptyText view when my list is empty. My code has buttons for getting the Detail info. I need to be able to implement a setEmptyVuew that utilizes a button to add a new crime from within the screen besides a Description stating that there are no crimes on the list.

Comment: The above example doesn't appear to be doing that.

Comment: yes, it just adds a button to an empty view, and attaches an OnClickListener to it. From there you should be able to proceed. Or let me know at which point you dont know what to do :)

Comment: I hate to admit it but I'm still confused.

Comment: added an image of what my code does. hope this helps. if not id appreciate a specific question, because i cant help with your confusion if i dont know what confuses you :)

Comment: What's confusing is having two separate views. One EmptyView (with a button) and another List View when I have one or more items saved. If there are NO items in the list, I want to display an EmptyView with a button. Whan I have an item added to the list the Emptyview will disappear and the list of items will display instead. The logic has to determine which view to display. The EmptyView (with button) or the ListView with the List of items displayed. Sorry for the confusion and I appreciate your help:)

Comment: The above code currently displays a message when the list is empty. I want to add a button to that specific view.

Comment: ah, now i get what you are trying to do xD gimme a sec

Comment: ok, changed my code. this should do the trick, but you still have to do some work yourself.

Comment: oops I found CustomBaseAdapter

Answer (score 0):

The default implementation of the `ListFragment` involves setting up a textView as the empty view for the list.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListFragment.html#setEmptyText(java.lang.CharSequence)

You can change this by extending a `Fragment` and create your own `ListView` inside it. you can use the code from the `ListFragment` if you like some of the things it offers.

As an alternative you can try to do `getListView().setEmptyView()` and set up the view that you need. Again see how they do it in the code in the ListFragment and reproduce it with a different View (instead of TextView use a Button or ImageButton whatever you need)

http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.1_r1/android/app/ListFragment.java

Comment: I'm new to Android. I made a number of chances and I my app crashes when trying to display the button. I only was able the get the setEmptyText to work. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Well keep on trying you will eventually figure it out. We all went through that phase :).

Comment: Thanks Can you give me another hint - where can I display the button in the above code? Or how can I implement it? I've been having a real problem trying to figure this one out.

Comment: did you see the code for the ListFragment. Just replace the the type of the emptyView variable with Button instead of TextView. Get the full code of this and copy it over into your own class, call it whatever you like, then extend it instead of ListFragment.

Comment: I'll look at the second link again. Not sure I understand what you mean,

Comment: I'm really stumped on this.